# How fix CorsOPTIONS for Rocket

Tags: rust, rocket

I found this solution for my problem on rocket_cors:

```
use rocket::http::Method;
use rocket_cors::{AllowedOrigins, CorsOptions};
    
let cors = CorsOptions::default()
            .allowed_origins(AllowedOrigins::all())
            .allowed_methods(
                vec![Method::Get, Method::Post, Method::Patch]
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(From::from)
                    .collect(),
            )
            .allow_credentials(true);
        rocket::build().attach(cors.to_cors())
```

but when I run the program I get an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `rocket_cors::Method: From<rocket::http::Method>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:37:13
   |
37 | /             vec![Method::Get, Method::Post, Method::Patch]
38 | |                 .into_iter()
39 | |                 .map(From::from)
40 | |                 .collect(),
   | |__________________________^ the trait `From<rocket::http::Method>` is not implemented for `rocket_cors::Method`
   |
   = help: the trait `From<rocket_http::method::Method>` is implemented for `rocket_cors::Method`
```

and i don't know how fix this

Comment: What versions are `rocket` and `rocket_cors`? I bet there's a dependency mismatch going on.

Comment: Please past the result of `cargo tree -d` in your question. This will list the `cargo` duplicate cargo dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest published stable versions of the crate (< 0.5.1) are not compatible with the latest versions of `rustc` and `rocket`.

You can use the development version of the crate using `git` + `branch` arguments in `Cargo.toml`.

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
rocket_cors = { git = "https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors", branch = "master" }
rocket = "0.5.0-rc.2"
```

Additionally the documentation state to use the `manage`-function instead of `attach`-function.

**main.rs**

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

use rocket::{Build, Rocket};
use rocket::http::Method;
use rocket_cors::{AllowedOrigins, CorsOptions};

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> Rocket<Build> {
    let cors = CorsOptions::default()
        .allowed_origins(AllowedOrigins::all())
        .allowed_methods(
            vec![Method::Get, Method::Post, Method::Patch]
                .into_iter()
                .map(From::from)
                .collect(),
        )
        .allow_credentials(true);
    rocket::build().manage(cors.to_cors())
}
```